# Positioning a widget with place inside the parent widget positioned by grid

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root = tkinter.Tk()

base_label = tkinter.Label(root)
base_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 = tkinter.Label(base_label, text='RESULT')
label2.place(height=100, width=100)

print(root['height'])
root.mainloop()
```

Question 1: How is the height and width of label2(positioned by place) affected by it being in a widget positioned by grid? label2 does not properly display the text 'RESULT', but this is not the case if the base_label is positioned by place.

Question 2: Why does root['height'] return 0?

Comment: Question 2: `root['height']` returns 0, because you are just trying to get the height **attribute** of the root, which is not set (I mean, you haven't called something like `root.config(height=10)`, right?). You should call `root.update()` and then `root.winfo_height()` instead.

Comment: What has the use of grid or place to position base_label got to do in this? Shouldn't the base_label expand to the size of the child label?

Comment: It looks like the base_label has normal position. Regarding the second question, it depends on the geometry manager and how do you use it. In your particular case -- no, it  shouldn't. But if you would, for example, use .pack geometry manager instead of .place, it will. Check it out (change the `label2.place(height=100, width=100)` line to `label2.pack()`).

Comment: 'it depends on the geometry manager and how do you use it. In your particular case -- no, it shouldn't' what does this mean? I don't understand why using place causes this problem even when I have defined the height and width? It would really help if you would refer me to a detailed video or something about using different geometry managers together.

Comment: `place`'s `height` and `width` attributes don't expand the size of the label2 but change the position of its text, hence the text goes down and right where it is not visible to the user. So you also need to change the parameters of the `base_label` (for example, try setting both width and height to 10). Now, you can see the "RESULT" text.

Comment: BTW, you can change the background (`bg` or `background` attribute of the widget) of both Labels and experiment with the widths and heights to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: How is the height and width of label2(positioned by place) affected by it being in a widget positioned by grid?

It's not affected by the use of `grid` at all, other than the fact that if the inner label is wider than its parent, part of it won't be visible. When you use `place`, it doesn't matter at all how the parent is managed. With `place` you are in complete control over the position and size of a widget unless you use relative placement and/or relative sizing. However, child widgets will be clipped by their parent.

In other words, the label added with `place` will be the size you requested. You've requested it be 100 characters wide and 100 characters tall so that is what it is. The visible part of the label will be constrained by the parent label.

> Why does root['height'] return 0?

It is because that is the default value of the `height` attribute. Getting the attribute doesn't get the actual height, only the value of the attribute. However, even if you tried to get the actual height it would only be `1` because tkinter hasn't had a chance to render the window. Until a window is rendered its size is indeterminate.

Comment: I get 0 for root['height'] even when I use root.update(). Doesn't using it render the window.

Comment: I get the correct value if I use root.winfo_height(). isn't root.winfo_height() equivalent to root['height'] since both are supposed to get value of the height property of the root.

Comment: @Dr.danks: "_ isn't root.winfo_height() equivalent to root['height']"_ - they can return the same value, but they can also return different values depending on various circumstances (eg: you can use `root.geomtry(...)` to give it a size larger or smaller than the configured value).

Comment: @Dr.danks: _"I use root.update(). Doesn't using it render the window."_ - Rendering the window doesn't affect the _requested_ size, only the _actual_ size. `root['height']` returns the _requested_ size. And since you didn't specify a size, it apparently defaults to zero on your system.